# Is possible to integrate vs code with vm-instance on gcloud with no public ip?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcloud, remote-server, openssh

I try to integrate with  vm-instance having public ip in it and it works.

But when I try to connect to vm-instance that does not have public ip,

```
Host my-host
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
  User user
  HostName instance-name
  ProxyCommand gcloud compute ssh --zone "zone" "instance-name"  --tunnel-through-iap --project "project-id"
```

I got message:
Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: The connection timed out)

Comment: Did you create the firewall rules allowing IAP? https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

Comment: I can access vm from my terminal if I run ProxyCommand above with my authenticated google account.
Is it mean that firewalls have been allowed?

Comment: Did you read the documentation link in my comment?

Comment: Yes, I've created a firewall rule as the documentation said. But the connection still timeout.

Am I should continue to the step "Grant permissions to use IAP TCP forwarding"?

Comment: Yes, you need permission to use IAP.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using VS Code Remote-Tunnels
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels#_using-the-code-cli

On the remote Google Cloud private VM:

1. Get the VS Code remote-tunnel

   `curl -Lk 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=cli-alpine-x64' --output vscode_cli.tar.gz`
2. `tar -xf vscode_cli.tar.gz`
3. `./code tunnel` This command downloads and starts the VS Code Server on this machine and then creates a tunnel to it. **Note**: You will be prompted to accept the server license terms when you first start a tunnel on a machine.
4. This CLI will output a vscode.dev URL tied to this remote machine, such as `https://vscode.dev/tunnel/<machine_name>/<folder_name>.` You can open this URL on a client of your choosing.

On your local environment, after authenticating and providing a machine name, you then have a couple of options for connecting to your remote machine:

1. Copy and paste the URL from #4 into your browser's address bar.
2. On a desktop instance of VS Code directly, open your command palette and run the command: Remote - Tunnels: Connect to Tunnel and paste the URL you got from #4

[Command: Remote - Tunnels: Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0LVa.png)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Push to [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs) - and either pull from there or use Cloud Build to deploy.